# Gridview row.Cells[i].Findcontrol finding control in wrong Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-2.0

I have a function I've written that you pass in the gridview row, as well as what control type you're attempting to locate. It finds the control as intended, however, it finds it in the incorrect cell.

```
protected int GetCell(GridViewRow row, string strSection)
{
    int intVal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        intVal = i;
        if (strSection == "QueryRate")
        {
            DropDownList cmbQueryType = row.Cells[i].FindControl("cmbQueryType") as DropDownList;
            if (cmbQueryType != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (strSection == "Name")
        {
            TextBox txtName = row.Cells[i].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox;
            if (txtName != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return intVal;
}
```

From my understanding, and directly from the Microsoft page: Searches the **current** naming container for a server control with the specified id parameter.

So my question is, why is this seemingly finding the control is the wrong column? I can't hard code specific columns, because the columns that show vary based on the the datasource.

Per request, the gridview:

```
<TDWeb:PageGridView SkinID="pagegrid" EmptyDataText="No unmatched parameters."  ID="gvUnmatched"  runat="server"  AllowSorting="True" 
                            OnSorting="gvUnmatched_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowDataBound="gvUnmatched_RowDatabound"  OnDataBound="gvUnmatched_DataBound"
                            OnPreRender="gvUnmatched_PreRender" OnPageIndexChanging="OnFilterUnmatched" DataKeyNames="InternalName"
                            ShowFooter="true" OnPageSizeChanged="gvUnmatched_PageSizeChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="c" FooterStyle-CssClass="c">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Add" />
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckbAddAll" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckbAdd" EnableViewState="true" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="c">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Ignore" />
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckbIgnoreAll" />
                           </HeaderTemplate>
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ckbIgnore" />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="l">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Name" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Name" />
                                <td:HelperBox ID="HelperBox5" runat="server" ToolTipText="Set the Name for this parameter. This value must be unique to the CAN Bus or ECU and is the value used throughout the DAP system to reference this parameter." />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" Width="250" MaxLength="256" style="background-color:inherit" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="l" SortExpression="Description">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Description" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Description" />
                                <td:HelperBox ID="HelperBox4" runat="server" ToolTipText="Set the Description for this parameter. This value is for informational purposes only. Not required." />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription" Width="175" MaxLength="500" 
                                    TextMode="multiline" style="background-color:inherit" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Length (bits)" SortExpression="LengthBits" ItemStyle-CssClass="r">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtSizeBits" Text='<%# (int)Eval("LengthBits") + (int)Eval("LengthBytes") * 8 %>' style="background-color:inherit" /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" AccessibleHeaderText="SourceAddress" HeaderText="SA" SortExpression="Sources" ItemStyle-CssClass="r">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtSources" Text='<%# Eval("SourceString") %>' /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" AccessibleHeaderText="ID" HeaderText="ID/Address" SortExpression="IDorAddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="r">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtIDorAddress" Text='<%# Eval("IDorAddress") %>' /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Data Type" SortExpression="Datatype" ItemStyle-CssClass="l">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txtDatatype" Text='<%# Bind("Datatype") %>' /> 
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" AccessibleHeaderText="QueryRate" ItemStyle-CssClass="r" SortExpression="QueryRate" HeaderText="Query Rate">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Rate" />
                                <td:HelperBox ID="HelperBox9" runat="server" ToolTipText="Set the Query Type and Rate for this parameter (if applicable). If set, this value overrides the default Query set below." />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCANRate" Text='<%# Eval("QueryRateString", "{0} s") %>' Visible='<%# m_SelectedFile.ImportType == App_Code.DAPConfig.ParameterFileImport.EImportType.CANDBC || (m_SelectedFile.ImportType == App_Code.DAPConfig.ParameterFileImport.EImportType.J1939DBC && ((int)Eval("QueryRate")) > 0) %>' />
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbQueryType" style="background-color:inherit" Visible='<%# m_SelectedFile.ImportType != App_Code.DAPConfig.ParameterFileImport.EImportType.CANDBC && (m_SelectedFile.ImportType != App_Code.DAPConfig.ParameterFileImport.EImportType.J1939DBC || (int)Eval("QueryRate") <= 0) %>' />
                                <asp:Panel runat="server" id="pnlRate" style="display:none" ><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRate" Width="50" MaxLength="6" style="background-color:inherit" />s</asp:Panel>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField runat="server" HeaderText="Category" ItemStyle-CssClass="l">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Category" />
                                <td:HelperBox ID="HelperBox10" runat="server" ToolTipText="Set the Category with which to group this parameter, or create a new category." />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cmbCategory" style="background-color:inherit" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="_New_" Text="Add New..." />
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <br />
                                <asp:TextBox Width="100" MaxLength="50" runat="server" ID="txtCategory" style="display:none;background-color:inherit" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
               </TDWeb:PageGridView>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your gridview markup.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing a FindControl in every cell in the row rather than at the row level? e.g. `row.FindControl(...)`

Comment: I'm looping through each cell attempting to find the correct row index so I can change the back color. As stated, the columns that show change based on the imported value.

Comment: by the way I'm reading your code, it's returning a cell index not a row index

Comment: @fnostro right, I meant the cell index, sorry. I'm a little frazzled with this code.

Comment: you said it's finding the control in the wrong column but you didn't provide specifics - which one was incorrect?

Comment: @fnostro They're all found when doing row.Cells[0].FindControl(). the case of the query, it should be index 8, and name index 2 in the particular case I'm working with presently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79707/discussion-between-fnostro-and-trasiva).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok - turns out that calling `row.cells(0).FindControl("")` is the equivalent of calling `row.FindControl("")` because `FindControl()` operates within the current NamingContainer.  And all the cells in a given row have the same `NamingContainer`, specifically `{System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow}`

If all you need is to determine the column index of a given control try this (pardon the VB):

```
Public Function getCellIndexByName(ByVal row As GridViewRow, ByVal ColumnName As String) As Integer
    For ci As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
        If CType(row.Cells(ci), DataControlFieldCell).ContainingField.ToString() = ColumnName Then
            Return ci
        End If
    Next

    Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks again for sticking with me and lending a hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID of the control that you are trying to find, you don't need to specify the cell.  You can find it by looking in the whole row.

```
DropDownList cmbQueryType = row.FindControl("cmbQueryType") as DropDownList
```

This way you avoid the problem of incorrect cell index.

Comment: That doesn't get me the cell index that I need however. I need the correct cell index for highlighting for error handling. I'd just use FindControl() if I needed the value.

Comment: OK, got you.  Can you find the control using the above method and then use [.parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) to find it's containing cell? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11008910/242) for an example of using .parent

Comment: I can, but I can't get any relevant information out of it regarding the cell index.

Comment: Here's another [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3172429/242) that might help.